# Sorting an the content of an XPathNodeIterator in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have a DLL which I (for many reasons) cannot change.  I use this assembly to retrieve a an `XPathNodeIterator`.

I know I can sort XML with an `XPathExpression` on an `XPathNavigator` to get an `XPathNodeIterator`, the problem is that I start from the `XPathNodeIterator` is there any way to apply a sort afterward?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`XPathNodeIterator` is non-generic `IEnumerable` of `XPathNavigator`. Thus, if you use .NET 3.5 and LINQ, you can do something like this:

```
IEnumerable<XPathNavigator> sorted =
     from XPathNavigator nav in nodeIterator
     orderby nav.GetAttribute("@id")
     select nav;
```

Comment: in any case, i tested this locally and it seems to work indeed, thanks
now i hope i can use this solution on the project (depending on if i may install .net 3.5 on the testing server and if the customer is willing to install it on his server)

Answer (score 1):

Since this type is an iterator there is no way to sort the contents without enumerating the entire iterator and loading the data into a different, sortable structure.

Please see [`XPathNodeIterator` Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathnodeiterator_members.aspx) for a list of the members that are available on this type (unfortunately, none of which support sorting).

Comment: There's no performance difference. XPath queries using `XPathNavigator` obtained from `XmlDocument`, `XPathDocument`, or `XDocument` are all non-optimized, and will use linear scans. So if you do the same yourself, you're not losing anything.