# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<System.Xml.XPath.XPathNavigator>' to 'System.Xml.XPath.XPathNodeIterator'

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-xml

I was wondering if anyone has an idea about the following error

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable'
>   to
>   'System.Xml.XPath.XPathNodeIterator'

Here is the code generating the error.

```
var randomNodeset = from XPathNavigator node in nodeset
    orderby Guid.NewGuid()
    select node;
return (XPathNodeIterator)randomNodeset;
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different sets of class for handling XML in .NET, the oldschool DOM-based classes and the new linq-to-xml classes. You're mixing them, which results in an incompatibility.

Here is an article on the differences between the two methods: http://dotbert.loedeman.nl/linq-to-xml-with-xpath

Comment: Agreed. @Sean, Does the return value have to be an XPathNodeIterator, or can you work with an IEnumerable?

Comment: Thanks @Anders. I will have a look at the link.

Comment: @Dizzwave - with umbraco they state the return value must be either int, string or XPathNodeIterator

Comment: I can't claim that I totally understand the answer to this one, but it *feels* like it *might* be of use (if you start with an iterator, and do the LINQ sort on it) :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363620/sorting-an-the-content-of-an-xpathnodeiterator-in-c